# How do I get Xtext's model from a different plugin?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, xtext

I've written an Xtext-based plugin for some language. I'm now interested in creating a new independent view (as a separate plugin, though it requires my first plugin), which will interact with the currently-active DSL document - and specifically, interact with the model Xtext parsed (I think it's called the Ecore model?). How do I approach this?

I saw I can get an instance of `XtextEditor` if I do something like this when initializing my view:

```
getSite().getPage().addPartListener(new MyListener());
```

And then, in `MyListener`, override `partActivated` and `partInputChanged` to get an `IWorkbenchPartReference`, which is a reference to the `XtextEditor`. But what do I do from here? Is this even the right approach to this problem? Should I instead use some notification functionality from the Xtext side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it out! First, you need an actual document:

```
IXtextDocument doc = editor.getDocument();
```

Then, if you want to access the model:

```
doc.modify(new IUnitOfWork.Void<XtextResource>() { // Can also use just IUnitOfWork
    @Override public void process(XtextResource state) throws Exception {
        ...
    }
});
```

And if you want to get live updates whenever it changes:

```
doc.addModelListener(new IXtextModelListener() {
    @Override public void modelChanged(XtextResource resource) {
        for (EObject model : resource.getContent()) {
            ...
        }
    }
});
```